# Install highest version of package providing given virtual

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, debian

We have hand-rolled debian packages in internal repos. The package has the version baked into the name because reasons, eg: driver-headers-8.12.12_8.12.12_amd64.deb

I want to always be able to install the latest / highest-versioned "driver-headers" package. So we make each one provide the nominal package name with matching version (in the debian/control):

`Provide: driver-headers (= 8.12.12)`

The problem comes when there are multiple versions in a repo a simple `apt-get install driver-headers` does not know which package to install since N packages are providing that virtual eg:

```
$ sudo apt-get install driver-headers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package driver-headers is a virtual package provided by:
  driver-headers-8.15.53-13-release 8.15.53-13.abcdef
  driver-headers-7.12.53-10 7.12.53-10.888666
  ...
```

It does however seem to know how to sort them correctly (the first displayed is the highest version).

Is this possible?

Comment: *It does however seem to know how to sort them correctly* -- Then what is your question? `apt` automatically downloads the latest available version.

Comment: I thought about this more: it sorts correctly because their names all begin with the same thing. If another package (say aardvark) provided "drivers-headers", then it would sort before and they would no longer be "sorted correctly". Which is the crux of the problem: apt can't rely on a lexicographical sort of package names to determine which best fulfills a given virtual. I think a meta package is the solution here.